# Python/Django - Starting apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Trying to get mod_wsgi started. Getting an fmod related reference error.

```
[root@host]# mod_wsgi-express start-server wsgi.py --port=80 \
>     --user www-data --group www-data
Server URL         : http://localhost/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:80:0
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:80:0/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:80:0/error_log (warn)
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
httpd (mod_wsgi-express):
```

> Syntax error on line 151 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:80:0/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so
>   into server:
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: fmod

Comment: Suggests that the maths library ``-lm`` is not present in the library flags definition of the Python installation. This has come up before a long time ago but can't remember the solution/outcome. You can try uninstalling using ``pip uninstall mod_wsgi`` and then reinstalling using ``LDFLAGS=-lm pip install -U mod_wsgi`` and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for you but give it a shot since you are using python3

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi 
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I think Mr Graham Dumpleton is referring to the solution he posted almost a year ago on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/L1iJeUpPTks

Comment: After hours of struggle, this worked for me. Thank you.